# Comportamiento inesperado del hook state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy experimentando con React intentando hacer un task manager app. Estoy intentando memorizar los componentes con memo, pero al hacerlo el state se comporta de manera rara, al completar una tarea haciendo click en el checkbox de 2 tareas distintas se descompletan otras adjunto gif para que se entienda a lo que me refiero:

[image: Image from Gyazo]

dejo el repo en git: https://github.com/FrancoRodao/learning-react

También dejo un codebox con el código completo: [image: Edit silly-visvesvaraya-rscvf]

Task component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import TaskRow from "../TaskRow";

const initialState = [{"id":1,"title":"1","description":"","done":false},{"id":2,"title":"2","description":"","done":false},{"id":3,"title":"3","description":"","done":true}]

function Tasks(props) {

    const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState(initialState)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!props.newTask) return
        newTask({ id: taskItems.length + 1, ...props.newTask })
    }, [props.newTask])


    const newTask = (task) => {
        updateItems([...taskItems, task].map((task) => ({ ...task })))
    }

    const toggleDoneTask = (id) => {
        let taskItemsCopy = [...taskItems].map((task) => ({ ...task }))
        let newItems = taskItemsCopy.map((t) => {
            if (t.id === id) {
                t.done = !t.done
            };
            return t;
        })
        updateItems(newItems)
    }

    const updateItems = (tasks) => {
        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks))
        setTaskItems(tasks)
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>learning react </h1>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Done</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {

                        props.show ? taskItems.map((task, i) =>
                            <TaskRow
                                task={task}
                                key={task.id}
                                toggleDoneTask={toggleDoneTask}>
                            </TaskRow>)
                            :

                            taskItems.filter((task) => !task.done)
                                .map((task) =>
                                    <TaskRow
                                        show={props.show}
                                        task={task}
                                        key={task.id}
                                        toggleDoneTask={toggleDoneTask}></TaskRow>
                                )
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}


export default Tasks
```

Task Row (task item) component

```
import React, { memo } from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"

const Tr = styled.tr`
    display: block;
    /* height: ${props => props.show && props.taskDone ? '100%' : '0px'};
    opacity: ${props => props.show && props.taskDone ? '1' : '0'};
    visibility: ${props => props.show && props.taskDone ? 'visible' : 'hidden'};
    transition: 0.2s; */
`;

function TaskRow(props) {

    return (<React.Fragment>
        {console.log('render', props.task)}
        <Tr show={props.show} taskDone={props.task.done}>
            <td>
                {props.task.title}
            </td>
            <td>
                {props.task.description}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox"
                    checked={props.task.done}
                    onChange={() => props.toggleDoneTask(props.task.id)}
                />

            </td>
        </Tr>
    </React.Fragment>)

}


export default memo(TaskRow, (prev, next) => {
    const prevTaskKeys = Object.keys(prev.task);
    const nextTaskKeys = Object.keys(next.task);
  
    const sameLength = prevTaskKeys.length === nextTaskKeys.length;
    const sameEntries = prevTaskKeys.every(key => {
      return nextTaskKeys.includes(key) && prev.task[key] === next.task[key];
    });
    
    return sameLength && sameEntries;
})
```

Encontré una solución que es utilizando setTaskItems como funcion, pero no entiendo por que tengo que utilizarla como funcion si no estoy modificando el estado múltiples veces.

Comment: SOLUCION: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365879/how-setstate-works-with-memo-in-react/65366276?noredirect=1#comment115564402_65366276

Comment: Puedes publicar la respuesta en español aquí y lo marque como aceptada para que las personas que se pregunten lo mismo puedan encontrar la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Parece que el elemento no se actualiza cuando los elementos o `props` no tienen actualizaciones. La actualización es en el niño, `TaskRow` que usa `task.done`.

Pero cuando no uso el niño y creo `TaskRow` en `Tasks` no hay un problema.

También cambié `let taskItemsCopy = [...taskItems].map((task) => ({ ...task }));` a `let taskItemsCopy = [...taskItems];`.

https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-thunder-csnmi?file=/src/components/Tasks/Tasks.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TaskRow from "../TaskRow";
import styled from "styled-components";

const initialState = [
  { id: 1, title: "1", description: "", done: false },
  { id: 2, title: "2", description: "", done: false },
  { id: 3, title: "3", description: "", done: false }
];

function Tasks(props) {
  const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.newTask) return;
    newTask({ id: taskItems.length + 1, ...props.newTask });
  }, [props.newTask]);

  const newTask = (task) => {
    updateItems([...taskItems, task].map((task) => ({ ...task })));
  };

  const toggleDoneTask = (id) => {
    let taskItemsCopy = [...taskItems];
    let newItems = taskItemsCopy.map((t) => {
      if (t.id === id) {
        t.done = !t.done;
      }
      return t;
    });
    updateItems(newItems);
  };

  const updateItems = (tasks) => {
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
    setTaskItems(tasks);
  };

  const Tr = styled.tr`
    display: block;
  `;

  console.log(taskItems);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>learning react </h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Done</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {props.show
            ? taskItems.map((task, i) => (
                <Tr show={props.show} taskDone={task.done} key={task.id}>
                  <td>{task.title}</td>
                  <td>{task.description}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      checked={task.done}
                      onChange={() => toggleDoneTask(task.id)}
                    />
                  </td>
                </Tr>
              ))
            : taskItems
                .filter((task) => !task.done)
                .map((task) => (
                  <TaskRow
                    show={props.show}
                    task={task}
                    key={task.id}
                    toggleDoneTask={toggleDoneTask}
                  ></TaskRow>
                ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Tasks;
```

Comment: Si bien a nivel practico si funciona mi intención no es hacerlo funcionar de esa manera, si no aprender como se comporta el estado con react memo, de todas formas gracias, pregunte en so ingles y me dieron la solución a mi problema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365879/how-setstate-works-with-memo-in-react/65366276?noredirect=1#comment115564402_65366276 gracias de todas formas.